# A página foi carregada através do HTTPS, mas solicitou um ponto de extremidade XMLHttpRequest inseguro

Tags: html5

Estou chamando uma API de repouso do aplicativo implementado Https para Http Rest API. Eu escrevi a lógica em VueJs. A chamada de serviço da Web falhou com a mensagem abaixo.

vue-resource.js:1091 Mixed Content: The page at 
'https://nomedapagina.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(anonymous) @ vue-resource.js:1091

através de solicitações  HTTPS da minha aplicação HTTPS - não há outra solução alternativa para isso e os protocolos de mistura também podem colocar a segurança do aplicativo em risco, mas mesmo assim gostaria conseguir rodar minha aplicação no servidor web, isso tudo por causa dessa linha de código abaixo

```
 created: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$http.get('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores').then(function(response) {
      self.bancodedados = response.body;
    });
  },
```

**Como poderia fazer para corrigir isso?**

Eu estou carregando uma tabela de cotação do dólar recebendo as informações de uma URL **HTTP** em forma de **json**

Comment: Você tem alguma parte back-end nesta aplicação? Creio que isto poderia ser resolvido se você acessasse primeiramente seu back-end e por sua vez, o seu back-end iria acessar a url desejada, e depois retornado para o seu front-end.

Comment: Não tem back-end, é somente um arquivo de html com incorporação interna de Javascript recebendo uma URL de http de um retorno json como mostrado nessa postagem.
Já que você falou que o back-end é a solução que tipo de implementação o back-end precisa para resolver esse tipo de problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está disponibilizando a sua página via HTTPS, em uma conexão segura, porém no seu javascript você está fazendo requisições a um endereço sem essa proteção, que no caso é a requisição para `http://api.promasters.net.br`. Como resultado você tem a warning ou mensagem de erro (caso o browser bloqueie a requisição).

No caso de bloqueio você perderá funcionalidades por não conseguir trazer o conteúdo desejado para o usuário. Se o browser apresentar apenas um warning, o símbolo do cadeado será exibido de forma diferente para indicar ao usuário que apesar de ele ter solicitado uma conexão segura ao seu website através do `https` existem requisições sendo feitas sem esse nível de proteção, então, o seu site não é tão seguro e pode estar expondo-o a alguma vulnerabilidade.

A respostas do tipo mistos não ocorrem apenas por conta do javascript acessando recursos sem proteção, eles também vão ocorrer caso você tente carregar até mesmo conteúdos estáticos como fontes, imagens, folhas css e ou outros arquivos javascript.

Para evitar o enfraquecimento do https, você sempre deve utilizar urls `https://` ao indicar referências externas ou simplesmente '//' que irá manter o protocolo da requisição inicial.

**Mais informações:**

[O que é conteúdo misto?](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content?hl=pt-br)